# Dapper and Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, dapper

I have 2 issues, hopefully both can be answered in this question.
I have a model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now assume that my Stored Procedure (which can't be changed) returns **first_name, lastName and UserEmail**. I would like to use some method (hopefully data annotations) to map the fields to the properties. Something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [Column(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "UserEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?
You may suggest making sure properties match the field names because they are not case sensitive, so changing **Email** to **UserEmail** would work, but it isn't for this reason. I have a class that has 2 **Person** assigned to it:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Mother { get; set; }
    public Person Father { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I can't use:

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

because it seems to ignore all other properties then.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Chain.

```
static Tortuga.Chain.SqlServerDataSource DS = new Tortuga.Chain.SqlServerDataSource (connectionString);

var people = DS.Procedure("procName", new { @Param1 =  x, @Parm2 = y}).ToCollection<Person>().Execute();
```

It honors the `Column` attributes by default.

---

Your second example is harder. You need prefixes so that it knows which FirstName goes with which property.

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Decompose("Mother_")]
    public Person Mother { get; set; }
    [Decompose("Father_")]
    public Person Father { get; set; }
}

SELECT x.nName, m.FirstName as Mother_FirstName, f.FirstName as Father_FirstName, [...] 
FROM people x
LEFT JOIN people f ON x.FatherKey = f.Key
LEFT JOIN people m ON x.MotherKey = m.Key
```